# Handle Multi-Tenant React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, architecture, multi-tenant

Basically i have a multitenant react app. I have currently 15 customers, which is deployed to Dev, Stage and Prod Env's. I am having different requirements for different customers irrespective of Dev, stage and Prod. what is best practice to maintain this architecture. Currently I am having conditions writing inside my code for specific customers to have that specific change.

I am using `React 15.6.1, WebPack, Redux`

[image]

Below is my configuration file

```
appConfig = {
    localhost: {
      param1: 'customer-det',
      param2: 'customer-det',
      param3: 'customer-det',
    },
    'Customer1': {
      param1: 'customer-det',
      param2: 'customer-det',
      param3: 'customer-det',
    },
    'Customer2': {
      param1: 'customer-det',
      param2: 'customer-det',
      param3: 'customer-det',
    },
    'Customer3': {
      param1: 'customer-det',
      param2: 'customer-det',
      param3: 'customer-det',
    },
    'Customer4': {
      param1: 'customer-det',
      param2: 'customer-det',
      param3: 'customer-det',
    },
    'Customer5': {
      param1: 'customer-det',
      param2: 'customer-det',
      param3: 'customer-det',
    },
  };
```

Comment: Maybe you can use something like [flagged](https://github.com/sergiodxa/flagged) to implement feature flags throughout your code and configure what customer can use what feature in a database. Now you only have one code base that all customers can use and you can configue custormer features in a database. When you search for "react feature flag" you'll find many solutions, some commercial and some open source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, the notion of identifying the tenant's within the code and rendering the content based on the tenant parameters is not a very flexible and scalable option.

Consider the following options

> 1. Single code base with Extension fields and dynamic UI rendering, this
>      helps each tenant to add custom fields to a base entity and see them
>      in the UI.
> 2. Having modules and licensing per tenant: In this model, you can build
>      various modules in the application and then package them, each tenant
>      will have a license that decides whether the module is accessible to a
>      given tenant.

This will be very helpful for you to `build new features, bill your tenants, track the usage and lots of benefits`.

The above option requires more thought process and might require rewriting some or most of the current code base. However, the benefits you can reap will be high in-terms of flexibility, scalability, monetary gains etc...

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination!